# rvest: button with no name (submit_form)

Tags: r, rvest

I have problem with button without a name  with `submit_form` from `rvest`. On this [site](http://www.lidl.cz/cs/2868.htm) is search form to filter different stores, but the button to submit request doesn't have any name and `submit_form` is trying to use other `input` as a button.

```
Submitting with 'distance'
Error in xml2::url_absolute(form$url, session$url) : 
  not compatible with STRSXP
```

I have tried to rename the button, but without any luck. How do you address such a nameless button? In documentation I cannot find anything about using xpath or any other way. Thanks for any help

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
rm(list=ls())
url <- html_session("http://www.lidl.cz/cs/2868.htm")
search <- url %>% html_node(xpath='//*[@id="searchform"]') %>%
  html_form() %>% set_values("startingpoint-city"="Kolín", distance="400") 
#hledani$fields[[5]]$name<- "button"
url <- submit_form(url,search)
```

Comment: All the "work" is happening in-page using javascript. You'll need to use Rselenium or splashr to work with the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [bug](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/issues/159) as of the rvest 0.3.2 version. Specifically *submit_form* calls *submit_request*:

```
submit_request <- function(form, submit = NULL) {
is_submit <- function(x) tolower(x$type) %in% c("submit", "image","button")
submits <- Filter(is_submit, form$fields)
...
```

In case *x$type* is a string of *length 0* the *%in%* function does behave as expected; long story short, the resulting boolean vector has smaller size than the original *form$field* vector.

I wrote my own *submit_request* like this:

```
submit_request <- function(form, submit = NULL) { 
is_submit <- function(x) tolower(x$type) %in% c("submit", "image", "button") && length(x$type)>0
submits <- Filter(is_submit, form$fields)
...
```

I suggest you to copy the necessary functions from the [source code](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/blob/master/R/form.R) and fix it as shown above until a new stable version is released.

Best Regards

CA